# Hive SerDe ClassCastException : java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I'm writing a custom Hive SerDe in order to parse logs (the goal is to parse the user agent into a complexe structure in a hive table but it doesn't apear is the code yet).

However, a ClassCastException apears when I try to put data in columns with a type that is not STRING.

My version of hive is 0.9.0

here is my Custom Serde :

```
@Override
public void initialize(Configuration conf, Properties tbl)
        throws SerDeException {
    String colNamesStr = tbl.getProperty(serdeConstants.LIST_COLUMNS);
    colNames = Arrays.asList(colNamesStr.split(","));

    String colTypesStr = tbl.getProperty(serdeConstants.LIST_COLUMN_TYPES);
    List<TypeInfo> colTypes = TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfosFromTypeString(colTypesStr);

    rowTypeInfo = (StructTypeInfo) TypeInfoFactory.getStructTypeInfo(colNames, colTypes);
    rowOI = TypeInfoUtils.getStandardJavaObjectInspectorFromTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo);
}

@Override
public Object deserialize(Writable blob) throws SerDeException {
    row.clear();

    String[] line = blob.toString().split("\t");

    row.add(line[0]);
    row.add(Long.parseLong(line[1]));
    row.add(line[2]);

    return row;
}
```

Here is the table creation :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logs (
  token STRING,
  tmstmp BIGINT,
  user_agent STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.hive.serde.LogsSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/Input/logs';
```

And here is the error :

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:173)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1382)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:412)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:563)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.JavaLongObjectInspector.get(JavaLongObjectInspector.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyUtils.writePrimitiveUTF8(LazyUtils.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:483)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serializeField(LazySimpleSerDe.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.DelimitedJSONSerDe.serializeField(DelimitedJSONSerDe.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:163)
... 11 more
```

Seems like all the values returned by the "deserialize" function are strings.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you post the query you ran to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `tmstmp` column in your DDL is a BIGINT. You're returning a Long whereas Hive is expecting a LongWritable. Try:

`row.add(new LongWritable(Long.valueOf(line[1])));`

Similarly, you may have to convert your Strings to `Text` using: `new Text(javaStringObject);`